# additional widget area in wordpress free theme spacious

Tags: wordpress-theming

### i want to add another widget area in wordpress spacious theme in the top section in business template just like middle section in the theme which has two widget area for which i have modified the code which is given below :

```
<?php 
if( is_active_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_top_section_left_half_sidebar' ) ||is_active_sidebar(
                       'spacious_business_page_top_section_right_half_sidebar' )) {
    ?>
    <!--<div class="clearfix"> -->
    <div class="top-one-half">
    <?php
     // Calling the business page top section left half sidebar if it exists.
    if ( !dynamic_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_top_section_left_half_sidebar' ) ):
    endif;
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class=top-one half top-one-half-last">
   <?php
    // Calling the business page middle section right half sidebar if it exists.
    if ( !dynamic_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_top_section_right_half_sidebar' ) ):
        endif;
        ?>
     </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
if( is_active_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_middle_section_left_half_sidebar' ) || is_active_sidebar(                                           'spacious_business_page_middle_section_right_half_sidebar' )) {
  ?>
   <! --<div class="clearfix"> -->
    <div class="tg-one-half">
        <?php
        // Calling the business page middle section left half sidebar if it exists.
        if ( !dynamic_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_middle_section_left_half_sidebar' ) ):
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tg-one-half tg-one-half-last">
        <?php
        // Calling the business page middle section right half sidebar if it exists.
        if ( !dynamic_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_middle_section_right_half_sidebar' ) ):
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php
}

if( is_active_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_bottom_section_sidebar' )) {
    // Calling the business page bottom section sidebar if it exists.
    if ( !dynamic_sidebar( 'spacious_business_page_bottom_section_sidebar' )):
    endif;
}
?>

</div>
```

---

I have also added following code widget.php which is given below:

---

// Registering Business Page template top section left half sidebar
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'              => **( 'Business Top left Sidebar', 'spacious' ),
        'id'                    => 'spacious_business_page_top_section_left_half_sidebar',
        'description'       => __( 'Shows widgets on Business Page Template Top left Section.', 'spacious' ).' '.**( 'Suitable widget: TG: Services, TG: Call To Action Widget, TG: Featured Widget', 'spacious' ),
        'before_widget'     => '',
        'after_widget'      => '',
        'before_title'      => '',
        'after_title'       => ''
    ) );

```
// Registering Business Page template top section right half sidebar
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'              => __( 'Business Top right Sidebar', 'spacious' ),
    'id'                    => 'spacious_business_page_top_section_right_half_sidebar',
    'description'       => __( 'Shows widgets on Business Page Template Top right Section.', 'spacious' ).' '.__( 'Suitable widget: TG: Services, TG: Call To Action Widget, TG: Featured Widget', 'spacious' ),
    'before_widget'     => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s clearfix">',
    'after_widget'      => '</section>',
    'before_title'      => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'       => '</h1>'
) );
```

---

but it is not showing the result instead it is throwing error.what is wrong????

Comment: Could you avoid cubital characters? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean?? where have i used these characters??

Comment: at the very beginning of your question ("I want to add another..."). **We are not blind**

Comment: Ok,but can you find where i am doing wrong in my code. the error showing is " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\suryaflame\wp-content\themes\spacious\page-templates\business.php on line 68 " in the first code in my localhost environment ? could you understand this?? thanks.

Comment: Actually I have posted question for the first time in this forum though I have reading answers here for very long time. I need the answer of this question very badly. may be there is some extra php mark-up but where ?? any help appreciated.thanks